# Why is Euler's identity ignored in the solution to an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the problem

> Find an explicit solution to the following initial-value problem, and identify the interval of definition
>
> $\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{t}{y(t^2-1)} = 0, y(0) = -4$

I solved it as a separable ODE
$$\int{y \space dy} = -\int{\frac{t}{t^2-1} \space dt}$$
and eventually got the general solution
$$y(t) = -\sqrt{k-\ln{|t^2-1|}}$$
which became
$$y(t) = -\sqrt{[16+\pi i]-\ln{|t^2-1|}}$$
with the $\pi i$ coming from Euler's identity ($\ln{(-1)}=\pi i$). However, on the answer sheet it says the correct answer is
$$y(t) = -\sqrt{16-\ln{|t^2-1|}}$$
My question is, why was the $\pi i$ removed from the solution?

Comment: Note that it's the logarithm of the *absolute value* $|t^2-1|$ not just $t^2-1$.

Comment: After integrating you'll get $y^2=-\log{|t^2-1|}+k$. Substituting here $y=-4$ and $t=0$ you'll get $k=16$.